# VIM - ? around filenames and tabbing spacing issues in nerdtree

Tags: vim

There seems to be question marks next to my files when I'm going through the folder structure on the left.

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Also -- 2nd part of the question -- I'm having trouble tabbing. Everytime I insert and write some code on a new line, it tabs too far and I need to hit a delete to get the spacing right.

Can anyone help with this as well?

Thanks

[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4aYxt.png)

Comment: Do you have any specific plugin installed?

Comment: One question for the question marks and one question for the tabbing, please.

Answer (score 0):

For the 2nd question (tabbing spacing), you can try, in "Esc" mode,

```
:set tabstop=2
```

You can change 2 to any number of spaces you want from each tab. You can as well include this in your ~/.vimrc, so that you don't need to type this every time.

```
set tabstop=2
```